# Простейший запрос, и ошибка INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO gal_files (file_name,id_albom,date_cr) VALUES (81982422.png,1,NOW())﻿
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near 'png,1,NOW())﻿' at line 1

Подскажите как решить.Я так понял из за точки ругается....

Comment: 81982422.png в кавычках надо: "81982422.png"

Comment: некатит 
INSERT INTO gal_files (file_name) VALUES ("81982422.png")﻿ Даже так

Comment: а ошибка в этом случае какая? Само sql выражение тоже в двойных кавычках? А если выполнить в sql-консоли или каким-нибудь phpMyAdmin'ом?

Comment: Дак в том то и дело ,что выполняю в  phpMyAdmin. А ошибка при выполнении запроса что в коментах
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '﻿' at line 1

Comment: `INSERT INTO gal_files (file_name,id_albom,date_cr) VALUES ('81982422.png',1,NOW())﻿` с одинарными попробуйте.

Comment: в каком формате данные должны быть в этом поле?

Comment: да будет эпично, если еще и форматы разные, но я думаю, была бы ошибка конкретнее тогда

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение, что надо еще проверить соответствие данных, которые возращает NOW(), формату поля date_cr

Comment: Приведите результат запроса

    SHOW COLUMNS FROM gal_files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо бы на хэшкоде добавить смайлы =) фейсПалм однозначно пользовался бы успехом

Попробуй

```
INSERT INTO 'gal_files' (file_name)
VALUES ('81982422.png')﻿;
```

или

```
INSERT INTO files (file_name) VALUES
('81982422.png')
```

т.е. переименую таблицу

Comment: А в чем смысл этого переименования?

Comment: избавится от подчеркивания, кэп

Comment: А зачем? MySQL с подчеркиваниями справляется. Более того, почему бы тогда и подчеркивание из названия поля не убрать? Текст сообщения об ошибки показывает, что проблема в области данных: ...near 'png,1,NOW())﻿'...

Answer (score 4):

Должно быть: `'81982422.png'` (с одинарными кавычками)

**Update**

Точку с запятой в конце запроса не забываем!

Comment: INSERT INTO gal_files (file_name) VALUES ('81982422.png')﻿

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '﻿' at line 1

Comment: А точку с запятой в конце запроса не суждено?

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ если черкз клиент то тчкзпт можно не ставить. Клиенты как правило сами это делают

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
INSERT INTO `views` (`file_name`) VALUES ('81982422.png');
```